# Hibernate query executes more than expected times

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have the below mentioned Entity relationship. When I run my application, I can see that the below query generated by Hibernate executes 13 times(1+12) where 12 is the number of rows I am displaying in front end application. Ideally it should have executed only once as I am not sure why it is getting executed 12 times. If I change my number of rows to be displayed in front end application to say 20, then query executes 21 times.

How can I resolve this issue?

**Hibernate auto generated query**

```
select employee0_.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER as EMP1_2_0_, employee0_.DEPARTMENT_CODE as  
DEPARTMENT3_2_0_, employee0_.EMPLOYEE_DEPT as EMPLOYEE4_2_0_, employee0_.DESIGNATION
as DESIGNAT5_2_0_, employee0_.EMPLOYEE_NAME as EMPLOYEE6_2_0_  from EMPLOYEES 
employee0_ where employee0_.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER=?
```

**Entity Classes**

```
   @Entity
   public class Project
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "EMPLOYEE_NUMBER", referencedColumnName = "EMPLOYEE_NUMBER")
   private Employee requester;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "APPROVER", referencedColumnName = "EMPLOYEE_NUMBER")
   private Employee approver;
   }

   @Entity
   public class Employee {
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "requester")
   private Set<Project> requestedProjects;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "approver")
   private Set<Project> approvedProjects;
   }
```

JSF UI Source

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="proj" lazy="true"
    value="#{projMB.lazyModel}" styleClass="projTableStyle"
    paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom" rows="12"
    rowKey="#{proj.projectId}">
    <f:facet name="header">         

    <p:column id="employeeNo" headerText="Employee Name" width="16">
    <h:outputText value="#{proj.empNumber.employeeName}" />
    </p:column>
        .....
        .....
```

DAOImpl class where for retrieving records

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Project> c = cb.createQuery(Project.class);
Root<Project> emp = c.from(Project.class);
c.orderBy(cb.desc(emp.get("projectId")));
c.select(emp);

CriteriaQuery<Long> countQ = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
Root<Project> empCount = countQ.from(Project.class);
countQ.select(cb.count(empCount));

List<Predicate> criteria = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
if (projectId != null) {
ParameterExpression<String> pexp = cb.parameter(String.class,
 "projectId");
Predicate predicate = cb.equal(emp.get(Project_.projectId), pexp);
criteria.add(predicate);
            }

TypedQuery<Project> q =  entityManager.createQuery(c);
```

Controller class

```
private List<Project> project = new ArrayList<Project>();
project = myservice.getDAOValues();
....
```

The table displays the following

```
Employee No, Employee Name, Project Id, Project Start Date
```

**Edit 2**

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "REQUESTOR", referencedColumnName = "EMPLOYEE_NUMBER", 
insertable = false, updatable = false)
private RequesterDepartment requesterDepartment;
```

Comment: What are you displaying in your UI? How are you getting the information to display?

Comment: @JBNizet I am using JSF Primefaces and I have included my JSF code in my question, please let me know if  have missed any information you had asked.  Thanks

Comment: I don't know Primefaces. What is the data you get in your controller, and how do you get it, i.e. which JPQL/criteria query are you executing? What does the table show?

Comment: If I am not wrong, you avoid n+1 behaviour with fetch join or fetch subselect: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching

Comment: @JBNizet I have updated question with details of code snippets from DAOImpl, Controller classes. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to load projects, and their respective requester or approver in a single query. This is done using a fetch join. In JPQL:

```
select p from Project p
left join fetch p.requester
where ...
```

And in Criteria, there is an equivalent construct:

```
Root<Project> project = c.from(Project.class);
project.fetch(Project_.requester, JoinType.LEFT);
```

Note that I renamed `emp` to `project`: `emp` would be an almost acceptable name for an Employee path. Using it for a `Project` path is extremely confusing.

Comment: If I do not have `project.fetch(Project_.requester, JoinType.LEFT);` then query executes multiple times and does this cause any performance issue or is this a good practice? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it causes a performance issue. If this issue doesn't have any significant impact, then you can choose not to care about it. But I would do the fetch join.

Comment: Thanks for your help, appreciated.

Comment: I have another doubt in relation to using fetch join. I have edited question as Edit 2 with another mapping of `requestor` attribute with another class called `RequesterDepartment` to get the name of the department which `requestor` belongs. In this case how can I refer to `RequesterDepartment` class in Criteria to use JoinType in order to get requestor department? Thanks